# How to properly finalize/cleanup pythonnet CLR objects?

Tags: python, c#, api, code-cleanup, python.net

I'm using python to communicate with a certain piece of software through the provided API. As the API-code is written in C#, I use pythonnet to import the DLL and subsequently use it. It is beneficial to do so using e.g. Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook when optimizing the code, as you can easily compare the results within your code and within the software. However, I run into an issue with cleanup. The API requires you to establish connection by running the following code

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference('API')
api = __import__('API', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
connection = api.connection()
app = connection.connect()
```

Now you can communicate with the software using `app`. The main reason for my issue it that you are only allowed to have one app in the CLR. If you want to create a new one, you should call `app.close()` and subsequently `newapp = connection.connect()`. What happens when you create `newapp` without calling `app.close()` is not clearly defined. I'm unsure how C# would handle this, would it overwrite the `app` in memory, would `app` now also point to `newapp`, or something else? With that, I'm even more unsure how python+CLR handles it.

To ensure that your would always work with a properly connected app, I have created a class that only allows one instance of `app` to be present. This restriction is implemented by evaluating `connection.Alive` through the API, which is True when an app is spawned and not properly closed yet. The class is similar to:

```py
class APIWrapper:
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.API = api
        self.Connection = api.connection()
   
    def connect():
        if self.Connection.Alive:
            raise RunTimeError('Only one live application is allowed at runtime')

        app = self.Connection.connect()
        return app
```

While this works fine, my issue arises when I accidentally do something like:

```py
wrap = APIWrapper()
wrap.connect()
```

When doing so, the app goes live and wrap.Connection.Alive evaluates to True. However, as I do not assign the return of `wrap.connect()` to a variable, I cannot close it using `app.close()`. For example, if I do:

```py
wrap = APIWrapper()
print(wrap.Connection.Alive)  # -> False
app = wrap.connect()
print(wrap.Connection.Alive)  # -> True
app.close()
print(wrap.Connection.Alive)  # -> False
wrap.connect()
print(wrap.Connection.Alive)  # -> True
```

I cannot close the connection anymore. I have thought about altering the class so the to just bind `wrap.connect()` to `wrap.App` and allow access through the attribute. This would solve the problem of losing the app, but I prefer to not have to call wrap.App continuously for code readability. Additionally, I am just wondering if there is a proper way of handling these finalization problems?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if calling `wrap.connect()` without storing the return value anywhere is the problem, then there is an easy solution for it: don't do it! It looks like the connection is a resource, so you must keep track of it to release it properly when the time comes.

In your example, what should happen to the previously created connection, when somebody calls `connect()` again?

Second, in Python there are two ways to explicitly keep track of resources:

1. [`with` statements + context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) (highly recommended). In this case you would need to implement a context manager on your wrappers.
2. `__del__` function, that you can define, that will be called when the object is no longer needed. This one you should avoid, because it will execute at arbitrary time, meaning when you try to create a new connection, the old one might still be around, because Python did not realize it should call `__del__` yet.

Another alternative is to make [a singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: I agree that I should not do it, the main reason I asked this question is that I am writing a wrapper around the API, and want it to be as robust as possible. This way, it allows to dynamically interact with the API, and ensures you do not have to restarteverything if you by accident call `wrap.connect`. I also looked at `__del__` as wel as at implementing `weakref.finalize`. `__del__` did not work as the connection was somehow still present in the clr and `weakref.finalize()` also did not. Therefore, I implemented it differently. (But will look at singletons!)